# PowerPoint VBA to bring group to front on click

Tags: powerpoint

I'm new to VBA so please forgive the ineptitude!

I have a slide with a number of points. Each point has a related Group of shapes that appear when clicked. Unfortunately, if the user clicks on them out of order, the later groups remain in front of the earlier groups. I am trying to create a VBA script that brings the specific Group to the front when it is clicked. Currently I have the below, but I have no idea how to adapt that to a specific group of shapes rather than the selection.

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).ZOrder msoBringToFront
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to do this during a slide show, there's a problem:  Since you can't select anything in slide show view, there's never any ActiveWindow.Selection object to work with.

Instead, you can give each of your groups a Run Macro action setting and assign it this macro (which must be in the same file, which you'll then have to save as PPTM or PPSM):

```
Sub BringToFront(oShape As Shape)
    oShape.ZOrder msoBringToFront
End Sub
```

The macro will then operate on whatever shape was clicked during a slide show.  There's more info about this at the link below. The code example above won't work on a Mac, but the link has a simple workaround for that.

Determine which shape was clicked

http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00141_Determine_which_shape_was_clicked.htm

Comment: Ah, that makes so much more sense now. Thinking ahead, is it possible to adapt the code so that it brings a different group to the front? E.g. You click on group 1 and it brings group A to the front?

Comment: @Roni Yes, but you'd need a way to identify the shape.  oShape.Parent.Shapes("MyShape").ZOrder msoBringToFront should work. oShape.Parent returns a reference to the slide the clicked shape is on, .Shapes("MyShape") returns a reference to a shape named MyShape.